# tkinter call a function after loading a folder with askdirectory

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a simple GUI where I am asking user for a folder and if the folder is selected, I need to run a function. The call never gets inside the `do_actual_processing` function.
what am I doing wrong here?

```
from tkinter import 
from tkinter import filedialog

def browse_button():
\# Allow user to select a directory and store it in global var called folder_path
global folder_path
folder_name = filedialog.askdirectory()
if folder_name != '':
folder_path.config(text=folder_name)
else:
folder_path.config(text='No Folder Selected')

window = Tk()

button = Button(window, text="Select Path", command=browse_button)
button.grid(row=0, column=0)

folder_path = Label(window, text='No Folder Selected')
folder_path.grid(row=0, column=1)

folder_path_txt = folder_path.cget("text")
if folder_path_txt != "No Folder Selected"
id_values = do_actuall_processing(folder_path_txt)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Fix the indentation of the shown code.

Comment: There isn't going to be anything in `folder_path` until `browse_function` runs, and it won't run until you get into `window.mainloop` and click the button.  You HAVE to think about event-driven programming here.  If you need to call `do_actual_processing` on the entered path, then you need to do it inside `browse_button`, where you fetch the path.  Remember, until `windows.mainloop` runs, nothing is visible and nothing can be clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple errors in the code given.

Line 1 : `from tkinter import`  -> This is a syntax error.

Line 8 : `folder_path.config(text=folder_name)` -> `folder_path` is not defined.

Line 9 : `else:` -> There is no if statement to begin with.

Line 12 : `window = Tk()` -> `Tk` was never imported (Relate to line 1)

Line 14 : `button = Button(window, text="Select Path", command=browse_button)` -> `Button` is not defined.

Line 17 :  `folder_path = Label(window, text='No Folder Selected')` -> `Label` is not defined.

Line 21 : `if folder_path_txt != "No Folder Selected"` -> The statement doesnt end with a colon.

Line 22 :  `id_values = do_actuall_processing(folder_path_txt)` ->`do_actuall_processing` is not defined.

A simple script which does what you are requesting is :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def browse_folder():
    folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if folder_path:
        print(f"Folder selected: {folder_path}")
        # Call your function here with the selected folder path
        # function(folder_path)

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Select Folder", command=browse_folder)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When the user clicks the "Select Folder" button, a file dialog will appear allowing the user to select a folder. If a folder is selected, the `browse_folder()` function will print the selected folder path to the console. You can replace the `print()` statement with a call to your function, passing in the selected folder path as a parameter.

Comment: Why do you call `root.withdraw()` as it will make the main window invisible?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply Shockshwat. the code is partial bit I copied from my workspace. It will have lot of issues.

Comment: @acw1668 i thought that only file browsing and function calling was required. I will edit it out.